# Need to export 60 million records from table to csv using ssis

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, etl, msbi

I have to export more than 60 million records from table to csv file.

Table contains 9 months of data. I have tried exporting based on date. That is for each day each csv file.
But it is taking very long time.

Is there any possibility in SSIS to export above data very fastly?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words here, people aren't going understand what are "crore records". Also, you haven't mentioned what your database is, do you have index for the day, how many columns are there, how long does it actually take now  etc. So, everything is pretty much just guessing

Comment: You have a database that you need to generate an export of 9 months worth of data. Is that 9 months into a single file or is it an a file per source date? What is the structure of the table and are you extracting all columns or a subset? When you tried the first time, why did it not work?

Comment: I learned from @billinkc to use bulkcopy (bcp)